# Is there a way to define a syntactic sugar in C# for an access modifier?

Tags: c#, syntax

I'd like to to shorten `[SerializeField] private` into `exposed`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not without modifying the Roslyn compiler, which isn't generally something to be done casually. You'll also be making your code base more difficult for new authors to understand by using something that is almost, but not quite, C#, rather than using C#.

Comment: If it's just a matter of typing less (it can't be about clarity because it would have *obscured* what's actually happening) , you could create an Expansion snipppet with a shortcut of `exposed` so that you type that word and hit tab, and it expands to `[SerializedField]`.

Answer (score 4):

The only feasible way to do so would be at compile time, i.e. with pre processor directives. You were probably thinking about something like [C++ define directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-define-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170), which can do exactly that. There is no such directive in C#. Here is [the list of C# pre processor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives), which does include `#define`, but with a rather different meaning as in C++.

All in all I'd say don't do it, as it will confuse whoever is reading your code. An old C++ joke comes to mind:

```
#define TRUE FALSE // happy debugging, losers
```

You get the idea.

Comment: I do indeed, but I have a solid reason to do this, as in Unity a private variable with [SerializeField] attribute is not exactly private. It is exposed in the editor's inspector and I wanted to provide another way to name it as the `[SerializeField] private` combination is neither public nor private.

Comment: Being exposed in the editor's inspector doesn't make it not private. The editor is not the language.

Comment: Would the `HideInInsperctor` attribute solve your problem? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html

Comment: Thanks @MaximZabolotskikh but that isn't the problem. We still want it to be in the inspector. Is just wanted a more specific access modifier for it.